# Is `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` equal to merge `git ls-files --others` and `git ls-files --exclude-standard`?

Tags: git

```
[root@localhost www]# git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
[root@localhost www]# git ls-files  --exclude-standard
app/third_party/jqgrid/css/ellipsis-xbl.xml
app/third_party/jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css
app/third_party/jqgrid/js/Changes.txt
[root@localhost www]# git ls-files --others 
info/folder/2016-10-08/69.html
info/folder/2016-10-08/70.html
[root@localhost www]# git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
[root@localhost www]#
```

Then I check status as below:

```
[root@localhost www]# git status
# On branch develop
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 2 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

System is centos 7.6 desktop.
Let's have a look of above `git` output.
I have something in `git ls-files  --exclude-standard`, and something in `git ls-files --others`.
Then,I think `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` will output all files not tracked,but output is nothing.
What's the matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary set of subcommands for `git ls-files` is [`--[cached|deleted|others|ignored|stage|unmerged|killed|modified]`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files); default is `--cached`. `--exclude-standard` is not a separate subcommand but a filter for one of those subcommands.

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard
```

is equivalent to

```
git ls-files --cached --exclude-standard
```

i.e. it shows all your cached files from the index. `--exclude-standard` here simply is not applied.

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

lists untracked **and not ignored** files: the filter `--exclude-standard` is applied to `--others` that is untracked files.

As your `git status` shows you don't have untracked and not ignored files hence the output from the command is empty.